# Is selecting trusted computer in 2-step verification less secure?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

In using 2-step verification, does selecting 'Trusted Computer' a less secure options? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2544838?hl=en

If so, is it still a reasonably secure option?

Comment: Do you trust those 'Trusted Computer' ?  
Are the only one to have access to them ?  
Do you lock your session ?

Comment: Are the only one to have access to them? - Yes. Do you lock your session? - Yes.

Comment: Then you can trust this computer IMHO

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for [security.se].

Answer (score 5):

Yes, making a device trusted is absolutely less secure -- but in general it is secure *enough*. The thing to consider is how easily someone could gain access to the trusted computer in question. Among the questions you'll want to ask yourself before making a computer a trusted device:

- Do you control the physical unit? (For example, is it in a locked home or in a key-card-isolated area of an office building?)
- Is the computer password-protected? (Do you habitually lock the screen when you step away, or have it set to lock automatically with a *short time-out*?)
- Are you satisfied that the unit is safe from intrusion through the network? (Do you have a firewall in place and do you keep the operating system and installed programs up-to-date with security patches?)

Comment: I would add you probably want to ensure full disk encryption on the system, if possible.